How to capture network packets in an nsenter environment?
I would like to capture TCP packets in a rootless docker network space.
After entering the network space by
dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh nsenter

I can't use tcpdump, it raises error:
tcpdump: Couldn't find user 'tcpdump'

I think it cannot find any user on the machine, because it cannot access /etc/passwd.
Do I have to specify a user to run tcpdump? Could I bypass it? Or is there any alternative tool to capture network packets in the specific network space?

Notes:

CLI only, no desktop experience.
iftop works fine in that network space.

